# NSFileManager, how to determine if a file or directory can be removed?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

Is there a way to tell, if calling

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL];
```

will fail?

Comment: If it exists and you have write permission on the file/directory and write permission on the parent folder, then you can delete it. For a directory you probably need to recursively check that can delete everything in the directory too.

Comment: The usual Apple advice on things like this is "just try it and see, don't try to predict the future".

Comment: Not too familiar with iOS, but if you're going to remove a file or directory on iOS since you (the app) are the only person that can create the file or directory I would assume it should be able to delete the file unless it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to check out NSFileManager's `-isDeletableFileAtPath:` which works for both files and directories 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/isDeletableFileAtPath:

However, you should probably heed the note listed in the documentation:

> Note: Attempting to predicate behavior based on the current state of the file system or a particular file on the file system is not recommended. Doing so can cause odd behavior or race conditions. It's far better to attempt an operation (such as loading a file or creating a directory), check for errors, and handle those errors gracefully than it is to try to figure out ahead of time whether the operation will succeed. For more information on file system race conditions, see “Race Conditions and Secure File Operations” in Secure Coding Guide.

Try to remove it and check for errors instead of passing `NULL`